# how to run task in background 24 hour without opening the app in android

Tags: java, android, service

actually im getting the data from the server phone number and the text message now using this im sending the sms on that number. For that im using the retrofit and calling retrofit every after 2 minutes if received new data then sending the sext message its working fine im using the service and handler but after destroy the activity task has been terminated.
when the app is running its executing the task but i want to execute this task every time.
im new in android please anybody can help me... how i can get this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be always active then you need to use a Foreground Service:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Note that if the user chooses to kill your apps service then that is their choice; you can't guarantee that it will always be running.

Comment: i used the foreground service but after one or 2 minutes its getting teminated why so ?

Comment: @DineshGangwar did you solve it? did you take a look at dontkillmyapp.com?